# IE11 Blank page preceding print screen

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I am currently trying to print a page on IE11, however when the Print Preview is shown there is always a blank page as the first page.
This is in my css code below. This first blank page doesn't show up in the Chrome print preview however.

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 99%;
     }
    #noprint{
     display: none !important;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .page-break
    {
           page-break-after: always;
      }
      .last-page{
            page-break-after: avoid;
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any page-breaks before the content that you are trying to print?

Comment: @Huangism nope i tried the `page-break-before: avoid;` as well and it didn't work. I hid a large section of content that formerly sat at the top of the page but I'm assuming making visibility: hidden it shouldn't be causing it. Especially since it doesn't show in Chrome

Comment: Hard to say what is causing it without seeing it. You could remove elements until the blank page disappears, that way you will know what is the cause. Start with `#noprint`

Comment: @Huangism I removed all the media print work I did and looked at the print preview and it was still there so I don't think it is related to any css I've displayed above unfortunately.

Comment: Actually I was saying removing the opposite of what you removed. Leave the print css and html there because that's what we need, start by removing the non print stuff. For example, I would remove the entire `#noprint` element, this is just for testing to figure out what is causing the issue, i know you will need that content for the actual page. You should be able to eventually figure it out once you get down to almost no content other than the print content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue in both Edge and IE whenever I put `page-break-after: always` on the divs involved. Had a hard time investigating until recently, I decided to review the rendered HTML tag by tag.

The issue was fixed by replacing the `display: flex` into `display: block` on all parent `div` tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It appears that the tr element automatically has page-break-inside: avoid. So, I added

```
  tr {
    page-break-inside: auto;
  }
```

and it helped.